# MetaSploit not connecting to database on OSX after installing Metasploit on separate account

Tags: database, postgresql, connection, metasploit

Before I start I would like to inform you that I own a MacBook Pro (Version 10.13), not Linux or Windows.

For the past year and a half I have had metasploit installed on my computer. It has had absolutely no problems, and I have ben using it quite a lot. I only had the metasploit framework installed on my personal account, and recently I decided to install it onto my student account (On The Same Computer), so I downloaded a package (.pkg) for the metasploit framework and installed it. It all worked flawlessly, and I was able to run msfconsole, I checked with db_status, and it said that it was connected. All perfect. But then, I signed in to my personal account, tried running msfconsole, and it did not work, I do not remember in detail, but it had asked me

> LOG: database system is shut down If your database is corrupt, would you to reinitialize it?:

Anyways, I'm in another situation now. I completely uninstalled Metasploit & PostgreSQL from both my accounts, then installed them back ONLY on my personal account. I set metasploit up; all smooth. I go to run msfconsole, and then this is the output:

```
Aryamans-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ msfconsole
    [-] Failed to connect to the database: FATAL:  password authentication 
    failed for user "msf"

    [*] Starting the Metasploit FrameworK console.../
```

I have postgreSQL installed; the latest version. And when I type db_status in terminal this is what I get:

```
    msf > db_status
    [*] postgresql selected, no connection
```

This has been a problem for about 4 days now, and I would really love if there is a solution to this.

Feel free to ask me any questions about anything else in detail, I will provide you with the info.

Answer (score 3):

I just found out how to solve it, it was just a problem with the database, so all that had to be done was to recreate the Database that Metasploit Framework uses, using Metasploit. Here are the commands:

```
msfdb delete
msfdb init
msfconsole
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to navigate into your folder like so:

```
cd /opt/metasploit-framework/bin
ls
./msfupdate
./msfdb
```

---

Manage a metasploit framework database

```
  msfdb init    # initialize the database
  msfdb reinit  # delete and reinitialize the database
  msfdb delete  # delete database and stop using it**strong text**
  msfdb status  # check database status
  msfdb start   # start the database
  msfdb stop    # stop the database
  msfdb restart # restart the database
```

---

```
./msfdb init
Found database config at /Users/ME/.msf4/database.yml, do you want to overwrite it?: yes
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

1.The Homebrew package manager includes launchctl plists to start automatically. For more information run brew info postgres.

*Start manually:*

**pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start**

*Stop manually:*

**pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop**

*Start automatically:*

"To have launchd start postgresql now and restart at login:"

**brew services start postgresql**

2.*Initialise* the Metasploit PostgreSQL Database With PostgreSQL up and running, we next need to create and initialize the msf database.

**msfdb init**

Sometimes you can have problems with your database msf  because you had preconfigured. I recomend you follow the next steps if the previous don't work.

**msfdb delete**

**msfdb init**

**msfconsole**

Good luck!!